# Rails: Curious about the best way to structure a "customize your product" flow.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a rails app where people can choose between different guitar models, and then they are directed to choose their color, then add an accessory like a footswitch, and many other accessory steps after this. All of the steps are dependent on the last step, because a picture needs to be shown on each step with the complete package they've currently built.

I want to build this in the cleanest way possible with rails, so I was wondering if anyone had any advice on possible structure. Different controllers and models for each step? (since each step will be editable from the back end admin area as well). Or some other structure that I'm not aware of.

Example steps:

1. Choose Guitar model.
2. Choose guitar color (many colors per model)
3. Choose a tuner (a couple tuners)
4. Choose a footswitch or bundle
5. Choose between lesson dvds.

Thanks in advance